# How to make localhost work

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I have installed WAMPServer 2.0i on my computer.
After having done so, i typed in:
http://localhost

it showed up as an error.

But if i type in 127.0.0.1 it shows the Wamp Server homepage which should show up in the localhost page. I have not done anything yet. I am not sure what happened.
Please help.

Comment: What operating system?
What is the contents of your HOSTS file?

Comment: not really a programming question but try clear dns cash?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Answer (score 5):

Edit `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and place the following into it:

> `127.0.0.1       localhost`

Answer (score 4):

Navigate to `C:/Windows/system32/driver/etc`. Then cut the `hosts` file and paste it in another folder on the desktop. Open it in Notepad and change `::1` to the `127.0.0.1 localhost` and then save it. Then put it back in `C:/Windows/system32/driver/etc`. Now restart the WWAMP and get it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `hosts` file.

It would be located in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and needs to have the following entry:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```